# Web scrape weather table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape the weather data, and need to take the table and convert to csv format. But not all the entries from table have same number of columns filled. So when i take the input in this format

```
for h in airports:

    for i in range(1,3):
          if(i==1):
              for j in range(1,32):
                  url="https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/"+str(h)+"/2018/"+str(i)+"/"+str(j)+"/DailyHistory.html?req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo="
                  www= urllib3.PoolManager()
                  page=www.urlopen("GET",url)
                  bs= BeautifulSoup(page.data,"lxml")
                  x=bs.find('div',{"class":"high-res"})
                  for tr in x.findAll('tr'):
                         weather.append([td for td in tr.stripped_strings])

          else: 
              for k in range(1,29):
                  url="https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/"+str(h)+"/2018/"+str(i)+"/"+str(k)+"/DailyHistory.html?req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo="
                  www= urllib3.PoolManager()
                  page=www.urlopen("GET",url)
                  bs= BeautifulSoup(page.data,"lxml")
                  x=bs.find('div',{"class":"high-res"})
                  for tr in x.findAll('tr'):
                          weather.append([td for td in tr.stripped_strings])
```

The out put csv file is all over the place, the comma seperated variables each are going into a new column irrespective of the headers. 
is there an easy way to do this and get the date in a clearer way?
[image: The table is in this format.]

So i am continuously appending a list with rows of the table, irrespective of the columns. How to make sure that the data in the columns is under the right header?[image: This is the csv output i got.]

This iss what i used to write the data into the csv file:

```
with open ('weather.csv','a') as file:
   writer=csv.writer(file)
   for row in weather:
      writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Why is this post tagged pandas? Also, what is wrong with first csv? Data looks consistent to me.

Comment: I used pandas to make this into a dataframe and write to csv. Also the data is consistent yet headers and the data in tables required do not match as the units and numerical data are stripped

Comment: I do not see any pandas code in your code snippet. Did you cut it off? Are we looking at your first screenshot? I see units inside columns. Is the first your desired result and second screenshot your current, undesired result?

Comment: Yes i cut off the data frame cde. and yes the top screen sht is of the table as in the website and the second is of the result i am getting

Comment: If data is in a table, why not use pandas' [read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html)?

Answer (score 0):

So guys the following seemed to fix my problem of getting the right data under the right column header:

```
for tr in x.findAll('tr'):
                     cols=tr.findAll('td')
                     cols=[ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
                     weather.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
                      
result=pd.DataFrame(weather,columns=["Time(EST)","Temp.","Windchill","Dew Point","Humidity","Pressure","Visibility","Wind Dir","Wind Speed","Gust Speed","Precip","Events","Conditions"])
```